# OpenAI GPT-3 API: How to preserve formatting when pasting content into an Excel cell?

Tags: excel, openai-api, gpt-3

I'm trying to create a fine tuned GPT-3 model.  to that end, I have some content that i've formatted in word that im trying to bring to excel (in order to import the training dataset).

My inputs are in the format:

```
*Point A
    *Subpoint A1
    *Subpoint A2
*Point B
    *Subpoint B1
    *Subpoint B2
```

However, when i copy the contents into excel, The excel cell converts this to:

```
*Point A
*Subpoint A1
*Subpoint A2
*Point B
*Subpoint B1
*Subpoint B2
```

Is there any way for me to preserve my original formatting?

Is there any other way better way than this?

Any help is appreciated greatly :)

Regards,
Galeej

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's definitely possible to copy-paste to Excel and keep the original formatting. What you need to do is choose [**Keep Source Formatting**](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/excel/keep-source-formatting-from-word-to-excel/m-p/2155993) under *Paste Options*.

**But, I don't think the fine-tuned model will return a completion with the original formatting (if that's your goal).**

---

**EDIT**

Try using the [CLI preparation tool](https://platform.openai.com/docs/guides/fine-tuning/cli-data-preparation-tool) to get some suggestions on how to structure the training dataset.

Comment: Hi, no the goal isnt to have chatgpt auto complete with the original formatting.  my understanding is that better formatted and structured inputs will help the fine-tuning process more.

Keep source formatting is not an option because the copy paste goes to each cell.  So for eg,. Point A is in A1 and SubpointA1 is in B1

Comment: Currently, my way around this is to add delimiters (:- when the indentation starts and :| when the indentation ends... :-- and :|| when the second level of indentation starts... i've written a def in my python code that loops through and creates the indentation programmatically.  however, the pain is to go back to each dataset and put the appropriate indentation

Comment: Aha, I get it. I edited my answer. Have you tried using the CLI preparation tool to get some feedback? Such a structure may not even be appropriate in the first place. Before you spend too much time on formatting, make sure this would be even appropriate for the OpenAI API.